# retrieve data key of selected row in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `button` (item template) in any rows of a `gridView`.
I want when user clicks on this button, I retrieve `dataKey` of row that there is that button in  it.
how can I do this?
(sorry,I can't speak and write English very well)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one DataKey and it is an int and the row of the button isn't necessarily selected and you have connected the following function to the buttons in your template field:

```
protected void RowClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button TempButton = sender as Button;

    if (TempButton != null)
    {
        GridViewRow GVR = TempButton.Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;

        if (GVR != null)
        {
           int ID = (int) GridView1.DataKeys[GVR.DataItemIndex].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the SelectedIndexChanged event. Something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
     TextBox1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
     TextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
     .
     .
     .
}
```